# Java Jackson JSON parse into Map<String, String>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to pass the JSON parsed map into some method which has following signature:

```
QUEUE.sendMsg(Map<String, String> data);
```

Unfortunately, I have no control on above method, and Jackson gives me parsed JSON in `Map<String, Object>`.

I need a `Map<String, String>` where

1. for the primitive JSON types, instead of Integer, Long, Boolean, I want its toString() converted value.
2. for the complicated JSON types such as List/Map, store the result in native JSON format in String.

For example, if the JSON input is

```
{
  "name" = "John",
  "marked" = false,
  "age" = 30,
  "tags" = [ "work", "personal" ],
  "meta" = { "k1" : "v1", "k2" : "v2" },
}
```

I want a `Map<String, String>` which has

```
map.get("name") returns "John",
map.get("marked") returns "false",
map.get("age") returns "30",
map.get("tags") returns "[ \"work\", \"personal\" ]",
map.get("meta") returns "{ \"k1\" : \"v1\", \"k2\" : \"v2\" }"
```

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Unfortunately, I'm almost new to Java, and has no prior knowledge of Jackson (I have to use Jackson for this solution).

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you like to return whole JSON object as string (keys tags, meta) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, implicit conversions should work as long as you make sure you pass FULL type information. So something like:

```
Map<String,String> map = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, new TypeReference<Map<String,String>>() { });
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...

```
final Map<String, Object> input = ...;
final Map<String, String> output = new Map<>(input.size());
final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
final StringBuffer buf = writer.getBuffer();
for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : input.entrySet()) {
  try (final JsonGenerator gen = JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(writer)) {
    gen.writeObject(entry.getValue());
  }
  output.put(entry.getKey(), buf.toString());
  buf.setLength(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `keyAs`. Please have a look at [Jackson Documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.7/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html) for more details