# how to declare a java bean for the below json structire

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have below json response as part of a webservice response ,where inner object name is value which is dynamic.Not able to understand how to declare a equivalent java bean...

```
{
  "error": [
    {
      "fea09b93175b626e4bb3d248ccb890bc": {
        "name": "80_5595_10.zip (5.0)",
        "error": [
          "Location path does not exist"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "5a8745c1967adabe9d492d3595f37ce1": {
        "name": "80_7208_01.zip (5.0)",
        "error": [
          "Location path does not exist"
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson - De-Serialize json with dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465273/jackson-de-serialize-json-with-dynamic-key)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way (example using Jackson).
I declared a bean as follow:

```
class Error {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<String> error;

    // Getters / Setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "id="+id+", name="+name+", error="+error;
    }
}
```

Your JSON structure is `Map<String, List<Map<String, Error>>>`

```
// Parse your JSON into a Map<String, List<Map<String, Error>>>
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, List<Map<String, Error>>> map =
    mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Map<String, Error>>>>() {});
```

You now have this Map structure

```
{ error = [
    { fea09b93175b626e4bb3d248ccb890bc = Error@36d64342 }, 
    { 5a8745c1967adabe9d492d3595f37ce1 = Error@39ba5a14 }
  ]
}
```

Then take each error element of the Map and set their id to be the same as their key. And add them into a List

```
List<Map<String, Error>> errorsMap = map.get("error");
List<Error> errors = new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, Error> errorMap : errorsMap) {
    String key = new ArrayList<>(errorMap.keySet()).get(0);
    Error error = errorMap.get(key);
    error.setId(key);
    errors.add(error);
}

errors.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

```
id=fea09b93175b626e4bb3d248ccb890bc, name=80_5595_10.zip (5.0), error=[Location path does not exist]
id=5a8745c1967adabe9d492d3595f37ce1, name=80_7208_01.zip (5.0), error=[Location path does not exist]
```