# Deserialize json string with nested array of objects with dynamic key

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, hashmap

Given the `JSON` string I need to convert it to my `POJO` named `TransactionInfo`

**JSON String**

```
{
  "transactionId": "EFODKKXHE003",
  "isSettled": false,
  "transactionProperties": [
    {
      "key1": "Value1"
    },
    {
      "key2": "Value2"
    },
    {
      "key3": "Value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**POJO**

```
class TransactionInfo {
   String transactionId;
   Boolean isSettled;
   Map<String,String> transactionProperties;
}
```

**Additional Note (From comment)**

After the deserialization, I want to access different keys in the `transactionProperties` map. If it's converted into a `List<Map<String,String>>` then it becomes complex. **FYI, the keys are guaranteed to be unique so in the end, I want one single flat map**. Another point, I don't need to serialize `TransactionInfo` back to `JSON`.

**What I tried**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, TransactionInfo.class);
```

But I am getting an exception like below:

---

Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Can anyone guide me on how to do that properly? Any help is much appreciated.

---

**Edit**

I have already gone through the following post(s) but none of them seems to match my use case

- [Jackson - De-Serialize json with dynamic key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465273/jackson-de-serialize-json-with-dynamic-key)

Comment: `[...]` represents *list/array* of elements. So instead of `Map<String,String> transactionProperties;` you want `List<Map<String,String>> transactionProperties;`

Comment: Thanks, @Pshemo. After the deserialization, I want to access different keys in the transactionProperties map. If it's converted into a List<Map<String,String>> then it becomes complex. FYI, the keys are guaranteed to be unique so at the end I want one single flat map. Any idea how to make it better?

Comment: "*keys are guaranteed to be unique so at the end I want one single flat map*" consider adding that information to the question since it looks like crucial requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Added this information to the question. @Pshemo

Comment: Also please clarify what should be result of *serialization* `TransactionInfo` back to JSON. Should that flat-map be split back to list of objects with single keys or to single object with many unique keys. If it is split back to array of objects then will their order matter?

Comment: I don't have to serialize `TransactionInfo` back to`JSON`. You can skip that part. @Pshemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the **keys** are guaranteed to be **unique** so in the end, I want one single flat map. Another point, I don't need to serialize `TransactionInfo` back to JSON.

Since all keys are unique, and you don't care about serialization of this POJO back into JSON, you can transform the list of maps into a *map* inside a constructor.

```
public class TransactionInfo {
    String transactionId;
    Boolean isSettled;
    Map<String, String> transactionProperties;

    public TransactionInfo(String transactionId, Boolean isSettled, Map<String, String> transactionProperties) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.isSettled = isSettled;
        this.transactionProperties = transactionProperties;
    }

    public TransactionInfo(
        @JsonProperty("transactionId") String transactionId,
        @JsonProperty("isSettled") Boolean isSettled,
        @JsonProperty("transactionProperties") List<Map<String, String>> transactionPropertiesList) {
        
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.isSettled = isSettled;
        this.transactionProperties = transactionPropertiesList.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
    }
}
```

Code-snippet from the `main()`:

```
String json = """
            {
               "transactionId": "EFODKKXHE003",
               "isSettled": false,
               "transactionProperties": [
                 {
                   "key1": "Value1"
                 },
                 {
                   "key2": "Value2"
                 },
                 {
                   "key3": "Value3"
                 }
               ]
             }""";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TransactionInfo transactionInfo = mapper.readValue(json, TransactionInfo.class);
System.out.println(transactionInfo);
```

*Output:*

```
TransactionInfo{transactionId='EFODKKXHE003', isSettled=false, transactionProperties={key1=Value1, key2=Value2, key3=Value3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves the problem to some extent but how can I pass the parameters to the constructor like above before the deserialization takes place? The answer assumes that I do have the `List<Map<String, String>>` already.

Comment: @1000111 You mean how to instantiate `TransactionInfo` in normal situations by passing a `Map`? You can preserve a normal all-args constructor, it would not interfere with JSON-deserialization (see update). I've just verified it on my machine.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. Okay, let me rephrase my query. Can you please show how to use your solution given the`JSON` string (using `ObjectMapper`)?

Comment: @1000111 You can use it like `ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); TransactionInfo transactionInfo = om.readValue(jsonString, TransactionInfo.class);`

Comment: @1000111 Exactly as you were using it with `mapper.readValue()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me to the solution, @AlexanderIvanchenko and Pshemo. Can you please also share your feedback about the original json string? Could it be made better to avoid complexity in the deserialization?

Comment: @1000111 You mean you're in control of the endpoint which produces JSON? And you're asking whether it is worth to change the way how it serializes `TransactionInfo` ? If no, I don't see a workaround *"to avoid complexity in the deserialization"*, if JSON-message remains the same we need to turn a list of maps into a map somehow.

Comment: Yes, I do have that control. I can change the endpoint that produces such JSON. @AlexanderIvanchenko

Comment: @1000111 Then, it's better to change the serialization to JSON to keep the constructor simple. You can open a separate question and provide the code from the Controller in which this endpoint resides. Feel free to notify me by posting the link here.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the type of the `transactionProperties` field to `List<ObjectNode>` then iterate over the list and for each element use it's `fields()` method to retrieve its members