# How to deserialize a Json Response which has dynamic key value pairs

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

I have a response currently like below, and I want it to make it in one line.

Current Reponse:

```json
[
   {
      "user_id":30826889,
      "hr":{
         "1664325660":65,
         "1664325720":65,
         "1664325780":70
      },
      "rr":{
         "1664325660":18,
         "1664325720":17,
         "1664325780":15
      },
      "snoring":{
         "1664325660":0,
         "1664325720":0,
         "1664325780":0
      }
   },
   {
      "user_id":30826889,
      "hr":{
         "1664340780":72,
         "1664340840":70,
         "1664340900":71,
         "1664340960":70,
         "1664341020":67,
         "1664341080":71,
         "1664341140":69,
         "1664341200":68,
         "1664341260":66,
         "1664341320":68
      },
      "rr":{
         "1664340780":20,
         "1664340840":20,
         "1664340900":19,
         "1664340960":20,
         "1664341020":19,
         "1664341080":19,
         "1664341140":19,
         "1664341200":21,
         "1664341260":22,
         "1664341320":22
      },
      "snoring":{
         "1664340780":0,
         "1664340840":0,
         "1664340900":0,
         "1664340960":0,
         "1664341020":0,
         "1664341080":0,
         "1664341140":0,
         "1664341200":0,
         "1664341260":0,
         "1664341320":0
      }
   }
]
```

and so on....

I want it like below to make it key value-pairs.
Like this;

```
{"user_id": 30826889, "timestamp": "166432xxxx","hr":65, "rr":45, "snoring":1 }
{"user_id": 30826889, "timestamp": "166432yyyy","hr":67, "rr":23, "snoring":2 }
```

and So on.... for every response..

I tried many things but couldn't succeeded.
Please guide, how can i achieve above..
............................................

Comment: First you have to make us understand the business logic you want to ,meet. E.g. from where hr 65 and 67 are coming. And from where rr 45 and 23 are coming. Similarly from where timestamp is coming, and how snoring is calculated in the resultant json? You did not tell about that.

Comment: Secondly, share your code of your most successful attempt. What have you tried so far. And what is not working in that attempt.

Comment: That looks like medical data in which the key is a timestamp. You probably need to deserialise it to an object and then do any aggregation you need. You can see how to deserailize into a map in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465273/jackson-de-serialize-json-with-dynamic-key

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Tell me whether this output is what you want.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "   {" +
    "      \"user_id\":30826889," +
    "      \"hr\":{" +
    "         \"1664325660\":65," +
    "         \"1664325720\":65," +
    "         \"1664325780\":70" +
    "      }," +
    "      \"rr\":{" +
    "         \"1664325660\":18," +
    "         \"1664325720\":17," +
    "         \"1664325780\":15" +
    "      }," +
    "      \"snoring\":{" +
    "         \"1664325660\":0," +
    "         \"1664325720\":0," +
    "         \"1664325780\":0" +
    "      }" +
    "   }," +
    "   {" +
    "      \"user_id\":30826889," +
    "      \"hr\":{" +
    "         \"1664340780\":72," +
    "         \"1664340840\":70," +
    "         \"1664340900\":71," +
    "         \"1664340960\":70," +
    "         \"1664341020\":67," +
    "         \"1664341080\":71," +
    "         \"1664341140\":69," +
    "         \"1664341200\":68," +
    "         \"1664341260\":66," +
    "         \"1664341320\":68" +
    "      }," +
    "      \"rr\":{" +
    "         \"1664340780\":20," +
    "         \"1664340840\":20," +
    "         \"1664340900\":19," +
    "         \"1664340960\":20," +
    "         \"1664341020\":19," +
    "         \"1664341080\":19," +
    "         \"1664341140\":19," +
    "         \"1664341200\":21," +
    "         \"1664341260\":22," +
    "         \"1664341320\":22" +
    "      }," +
    "      \"snoring\":{" +
    "         \"1664340780\":0," +
    "         \"1664340840\":0," +
    "         \"1664340900\":0," +
    "         \"1664340960\":0," +
    "         \"1664341020\":0," +
    "         \"1664341080\":0," +
    "         \"1664341140\":0," +
    "         \"1664341200\":0," +
    "         \"1664341260\":0," +
    "         \"1664341320\":0" +
    "      }" +
    "   }" +
    "]");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(user_id," +
    "    items: collect(hr.entries().map(key, hr:value)," +
    "                   rr.entries().map(key, rr:value)," +
    "                   snoring.entries().map(key, snoring:value))" +
    "           .flatten()" +
    "           .group(key, field(key:))" +
    "           .map(timestamp:key, elements.hr[0], elements.rr[0], elements.snoring[0])" +
    ")" +
    ".unwind(items)");

for (JsonNode elem : node) {
    System.out.println(elem.toString());
}
```

Output

```
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325660","hr":65,"rr":18,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325720","hr":65,"rr":17,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325780","hr":70,"rr":15,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340780","hr":72,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340840","hr":70,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340900","hr":71,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340960","hr":70,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341020","hr":67,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341080","hr":71,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341140","hr":69,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341200","hr":68,"rr":21,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341260","hr":66,"rr":22,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341320","hr":68,"rr":22,"snoring":0}
```

Comment: Thanks.. @raymond-choi
It's working! i just need to have each of these as a one output to store it in Influx-DB. 
Is it possible?
Like;
`{
  "user_id" : 30826889,
  "timestamp" : "1664325660",
  "hr" : 65,
  "rr" : 18,
  "snoring" : 0
}`
And so on for others

Comment: Can i make it like a loop..?

Comment: BTW, please study `Jackson` and learn how to use the basic operation on JSON.

Comment: The _Josson_ query also work for your updated JSON array. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    File src = new File("e:/in.json");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Map<String, Object>> items = mapper.readValue(src, new TypeReference<>() {
    });

    for (Map<String, Object> map : convert(items))
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
}

public static List<Map<String, Object>> convert(List<Map<String, Object>> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .flatMap(item -> convert(item).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static List<Map<String, Object>> convert(Map<String, Object> item) {
    return getUniqueTimes(item.values()).stream()
                                        .map(time -> createTimeItem(item, time))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Set<String> getUniqueTimes(Collection<Object> values) {
    return values.stream()
                 .filter(value -> value instanceof Map)
                 .flatMap(value -> ((Map<String, Integer>)value).keySet().stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private static Map<String, Object> createTimeItem(Map<String, Object> item, String timestamp) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("user_id", item.get("user_id"));
    map.put("timestamp", timestamp);

    item.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Map)
        .forEach(entry -> map.put(entry.getKey(), ((Map<String, Integer>)entry.getValue()).get(timestamp)));

    return map;
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325720","hr":65,"rr":17,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325780","hr":70,"rr":15,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664325660","hr":65,"rr":18,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340900","hr":71,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341260","hr":66,"rr":22,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340840","hr":70,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341080","hr":71,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341320","hr":68,"rr":22,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341200","hr":68,"rr":21,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340960","hr":70,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341140","hr":69,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664341020","hr":67,"rr":19,"snoring":0}
{"user_id":30826889,"timestamp":"1664340780","hr":72,"rr":20,"snoring":0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Javascript:

```js
const inputArray = [
  {
    "user_id":30826889,
    "hr": {
      "1664325660": 65,
      "1664325720": 65,
      "1664325780": 70
    },
    "rr": {
      "1664325660":18,
      "1664325720":17,
      "1664325780":15
    },
    "snoring": {
      "1664325660": 0,
      "1664325720": 0,
      "1664325780": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "user_id": 30826889,
    "hr": {
      "1664340780":72,
      "1664340840": 70,
      "1664340900": 71,
      "1664340960": 70,
      "1664341020": 67,
      "1664341080": 71,
      "1664341140": 69,
      "1664341200": 68,
      "1664341260": 66,
      "1664341320": 68
    },
    "rr":{
      "1664340780": 20,
      "1664340840": 20,
      "1664340900": 19,
      "1664340960": 20,
      "1664341020": 19,
      "1664341080": 19,
      "1664341140": 19,
      "1664341200": 21,
      "1664341260": 22,
      "1664341320": 22
    },
    "snoring":{
      "1664340780": 0,
      "1664340840": 0,
      "1664340900": 0,
      "1664340960": 0,
      "1664341020": 0,
      "1664341080": 0,
      "1664341140": 0,
      "1664341200": 0,
      "1664341260": 0,
      "1664341320": 0
    }
  }
];

//  {"user_id": 30826889, "timestamp": "166432xxxx","hr":65, "rr":45, "snoring":1 }
//  {"user_id": 30826889, "timestamp": "166432yyyy","hr":67, "rr":23, "snoring":2 }

for (const { user_id, hr, rr, snoring } of inputArray) {
  for (const timestamp of Object.keys(hr)) {
    const result = { user_id, timestamp, hr: hr[timestamp], rr: rr[timestamp], snoring: snoring[timestamp] };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
  }
}
```